# Why do I need a prime read in c++?

Tags: c++14

I have been back and forth with my professor regarding why a prime read is or is not needed in c++.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int addFunct(int& total, int& rNum);

int subFunct(int& total, int& rNum);


int main() {

    char op1;

    int rNum = 0;

    int total = 0;


    std::ifstream inFile;

    inFile.open("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\c++ files\\input.txt");
    if (inFile.fail()) {

        std::cout << "no read";
    }


    do {

        inFile >> op1 >> rNum;
        if (op1 == '+') {

            addFunct(total, rNum);

        }

        else if (op1 == '-') {

            subFunct(total, rNum);
        }

    }

    while (!inFile.eof());     //super while loop


    inFile.close();

    std::cout << "El total es: " << total;

    return 0;


}

int addFunct(int& total, int& rNum) {

    total = total + rNum;


    return total;

}

int subFunct(int& total, int& rNum) {

    total = total - rNum;

    return total;

}
```

If I place a prime read above my DO statement (e.g. inFile >> op1 >> rNum;) then the last value in the file will not be read. However, my professor argues that priming a read is important and necessary. I am wondering why this is and how I can resolve the issue of not performing operations on the last read in number.

Comment: And by *prime read* you mean... any reading operation executed as the first one in regard to a certain stream? Anyway, the safest and most reliable way of doing that is `while (inFile >> op1 >> rNum) { ... }`. Both you and your professor should read [why `f.eof()` is almost always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feoffile-always-wrong).

Comment: Besides, "*However, my professor argues that priming a read is important and necessary.*" - have you considered *asking them **why*** he claims that?

Comment: Yes and yes. Commented under your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why do I need a prime read in c++?

You don't.

> However, my professor argues that priming a read is important and necessary.

Did you ask them for an explanation? Or they just stated that and refused to explain?

---

To elaborate - both your and your professor's approaches are wrong. Both because they use `std::fstream::eof` as the loop condition, which is [almost always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feoffile-always-wrong).

What you should do is move the reading to the loop condition, like so:

```
while (inFile >> op1 >> rNum) {
    if (op1 == '+') {
        addFunct(total, rNum);
    }
    else if (op1 == '-') {
        subFunct(total, rNum);
    }
}
```

This way you will not miss any data from the file. You will also correctly not enter the loop as soon as the reading fails, either due to end-of-file or inability to parse file content to `char` followed by an `int`.

This works because if a `>>` read fails, it sets certain *failbits* of the associated stream. Then, the `>>` operator returns the stream itself (in this case `inFile`) which is *implicitly convertible* to `bool`. It evaluates to `true` if there are no failbits set and to `false` otherwise.

Comment: Professor could not offer an explanation which puzzles me. I pressed for an answer and even received points off for not using a prime read, however, even after much research, I never found an answer to satisfy needing a prime read. Thank you for your explanation (especially the in-depth part) and for linking the other stackoverflow question. Your expertise is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Priming read just loads the while loop for the first time it tests the condition. I think the professor thought it was important because it is a standard way to setup while loops for structured programing and Flow charting.